# How to completed the full process or rollback to original form in yii?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

How to completed the full process or rollback to original form in `yii`?

Example:
I have to update 5 tables in my database at once. Due to abnormal termination only 2 tables get updated. I want to either update all 5 tables or to rollback to original form.

I will be happy if someone answer me quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Put your queries in a `try {} catch {}` construction, and use [transactions.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#using-transactions) If a query fails for whatever reason, the rollback will be executed.